# EasyListView Component with Styled Scrollbar

Tags: listview, delphi, styles, scrollbar

My Delphi application uses the EasyListView component. I really love it, but unfortunately the scroll bar is not style/theme aware. I have looked into the code and it uses its own TEasyScrollbarManager. Is there someone who also uses this component and happens to have a fix for this?

The source is here:

[Mustangpeak EasyListview](https://github.com/TurboPack/MustangpeakEasyListview)

Comment: You should probably add an issue there: https://github.com/TurboPack/MustangpeakEasyListview/issues

Comment: That is a good idea, thank you!